# Can you explain the usage of VALUES in this case?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: Picture of the situation]
This is the code for the measure:

```
Sales of Audio (VALUES) = 
CALCULATE(
    [Total Sales],
    'Product Category'[Category] = "Audio",
    VALUES( 'Product Category'[Category] )
)
```

In the table, it doesn't show the sales of every category other than Audio? Why are these rows blank?
I don't really understand how VALUES works here?
Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is restoring the filter context.

```
'Product Category'[Category] = "Audio"
```

is internally rewritten as

```
ALL( 'Product Category'[Category]) = "Audio"
```

which destroys the filter context and gives you the same value for every row. VALUES() then restores the filter on Category.

Comment: I like the way you explain the functions: the one that destroys and the one that restore. But why are sales for categories other than Audio blank?

Comment: Because you have restored the filter context. i.e. the second row filter context is "Audio" & "Cameras & Camcorder". There are no products with two categories like this so it is blank. The first row is "Audio" & "Audio" which obviously does give a match.

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is because, `VALUES( 'Product Category'[Category])` With filter as `'Product Category'[Category] = "Audio"` is resulting only in table with "Audio" in the category field and when your CALCULATE measure is trying to calculate the values for other categories like cameras,cellphones etc (which are not present) in the table, Hence they are shown as blank.